# element "textarea" show only value of placeholder even having value evaluated

Tags: html

At first time of being refreshed, element "textarea" renders the value of placeholder even value is evaluated.Is it a bug?
For example:

```
  <textarea class="vTextField" name="description" value="0000" placeholder="test"></textarea>
```

shows [test   ]

While 'input' element works just fine.

So, how could make it to render a big inputbox like 'textarea' while it functions like "input"?

Comment: Can you provide working example? Maybe you have JS that resets textarea text to placeholder value?

Comment: You have to wreite value in between two tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use value for text area .Place the content between  the  opening and closing tags. textarea tag doesnt have value attribute

```html
<textarea class="vTextField" name="description" placeholder="test">0000</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have a pre-set value in your textarea? It doesn't work with `value` for textareas. You have to write the value in between the two tags (that's why the two are there):

```html
<textarea class="vTextField" name="description" placeholder="test">0000</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If v want to display the contents in text area of textbox v use text area tag with class,row,column,name attributes and contents between the opening and closing tag

```
<textarea class="class name"  name="name" placeholder="test">0000</textarea>
```